# 3D Visualization of XYZ points in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am currently developing an UWP application in Visual Studio 2017, in which I have a list of points in a table. I would like to represent the points present within this table in a 3 axes reference allowing a 3D visualization of these points.

[image]

For the moment I have found only tools allowing me to make 2 dimensions.

Do you know free tools which could help me?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confuse about your requirement, could you share a screenshot to explain this ?

Comment: I added a screenshot of my points table ! I would like to display those points in a 3D graphics like a surface chart on excel. I Don't know if it's possible in UWP.

Comment: Unfortunately , there is no such control in uwp platform that could render  3D graphics like a surface chart on excel. May be you could search third part library to approach that.